# How to remove archived posts from pagination in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, archive

I've built a Jekyll blog that includes a post archive. I developed the archive using the `jekyll-archives` plugin. I'm happy with the website and the archive pages are working fine. The problem is that archived posts are also shown on the current website, which is built with `jekyll-paginate`.

I don't want archived posts to be shown on the current website because archived posts should be "archived" and only be accessible through the archive pages. Suppose I have posts from 2020 until 2022. I want 2021 and 2020 posts to be archived and appear on the archive pages only whilst the current paginated website lists 2022 posts only. How do I achieve this effect?

My `jekyll-archives` configuration in `_config.yml` file:

```
jekyll-archives:
  enabled: all
  layout: archive
  permalinks: 
    year: '/blogs/archives/:year/'
  title: 'Archived :year'
```

My archive template code:

```
<h1>Archive of posts from {{ page.date | date: "%Y" }}</h1>

<ul class="posts">
{% for post in page.posts %}
  <li>
    <span class="post-date">{{ post.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</span>
    <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | relative_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to the problem. To remove the archived posts from the current website (`/blogs/`), I first set the `permalink` value to the directory in which I want to keep the archived posts. For instance, `/blogs/archives/:year/:title/`. Then I ran the `jekyll-archives` plugin to archive the markdown-based posts. All posts are saved in `_posts` folder like a standard Jekyll blog. After that I copied all the generated HTML pages from the `_site` folder to the site's archive directory as defined above, removed all the markdown source files of the archived posts from `_posts` and set the `permalink` value back to the current website `/blogs/`. When I re-ran `bundle exec jekyll serve`, the archived posts remain accessible at where they should be whilst being removed from the current website. If there's a more `Jekyllist` (smarter) solution, I'd love to know!